# OpenSSL SHA256 Wrong result

Tags: c++, windows, openssl, sha

I have following piece of code that is supposed to calculate the `SHA256` of a file. I am reading the file chunk by chunk and using `EVP_DigestUpdate` for the chunk. When I test the code with the file that has content

`Test Message
 Hello World`

in Windows, it gives me SHA256 value of `97b2bc0cd1c3849436c6532d9c8de85456e1ce926d1e872a1e9b76a33183655f` but the value is supposed to be `318b20b83a6730b928c46163a2a1cefee4466132731c95c39613acb547ccb715`, which can be verified [here too](http://www.xorbin.com/tools/sha256-hash-calculator).

Here is the code:

```
#include <openssl\evp.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <fstream>
#include <cstdio>
const int MAX_BUFFER_SIZE = 1024;
std::string FileChecksum(std::string, std::string);
int main()
{
    std::string checksum = FileChecksum("C:\\Users\\Dell\\Downloads\\somefile.txt","sha256");
    std::cout << checksum << std::endl;
    return 0;
}

std::string FileChecksum(std::string file_path, std::string algorithm)
{
     EVP_MD_CTX *mdctx;
     const EVP_MD *md;
     unsigned char md_value[EVP_MAX_MD_SIZE];
     int i;
     unsigned int md_len;

     OpenSSL_add_all_digests();
     md = EVP_get_digestbyname(algorithm.c_str());

     if(!md) {
            printf("Unknown message digest %s\n",algorithm);
            exit(1);
     }

     mdctx = EVP_MD_CTX_create();
     std::ifstream readfile(file_path,std::ifstream::in|std::ifstream::binary);
     if(!readfile.is_open())
     {
         std::cout << "COuldnot open file\n";
         return 0;
     }
     readfile.seekg(0, std::ios::end);
     long filelen = readfile.tellg();
     std::cout << "LEN IS " << filelen << std::endl;
     readfile.seekg(0, std::ios::beg);
     if(filelen == -1)
     {
         std::cout << "Return Null \n";
         return 0;
     }

     EVP_DigestInit_ex(mdctx, md, NULL);
     long temp_fil = filelen;
     while(!readfile.eof() && readfile.is_open() && temp_fil>0)
     {

         int bufferS = (temp_fil < MAX_BUFFER_SIZE) ? temp_fil : MAX_BUFFER_SIZE;
         char *buffer = new char[bufferS+1];
         buffer[bufferS] = 0;
         readfile.read(buffer, bufferS);
         std::cout << strlen(buffer) << std::endl;
         EVP_DigestUpdate(mdctx, buffer, strlen(buffer));
         temp_fil -= bufferS;
         delete[] buffer;
     }
     EVP_DigestFinal_ex(mdctx, md_value, &md_len);
     EVP_MD_CTX_destroy(mdctx);

     printf("Digest is: ");
     //char *checksum_msg = new char[md_len];
     //int cx(0);
     for(i = 0; i < md_len; i++)
     {
        //_snprintf(checksum_msg+cx,md_len-cx,"%02x",md_value[i]);
         printf("%02x", md_value[i]);
     }
     //std::string res(checksum_msg);
     //delete[] checksum_msg;

     printf("\n");

     /* Call this once before exit. */
     EVP_cleanup();
     return "";
}
```

I tried to write the hash generated by program as string using `_snprintf` but it didn't worked. How can I generate the correct hash and return the value as string from `FileChecksum` Function? Platform is Windows.

**EDIT:**  It seems the problem was because of `CRLF` issue. As Windows in saving file using `\r\n`, the Checksum calculated was different. How to handle this?

Comment: Your example input should be `Test Message\nHello World\n`.

Comment: please refer to question again. I have updated details.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems the problem was associated with the value of length I passed in  `EVP_DigestUpdate`. I had passed value from `strlen`, but replacing it with `bufferS` did fixed the issue. 
The code was modified as:

```
while(!readfile.eof() && readfile.is_open() && temp_fil>0)
{
  int bufferS = (temp_fil < MAX_BUFFER_SIZE) ? temp_fil : MAX_BUFFER_SIZE;
  char *buffer = new char[bufferS+1];
  buffer[bufferS] = 0;
  readfile.read(buffer, bufferS);
  EVP_DigestUpdate(mdctx, buffer, bufferS);
  temp_fil -= bufferS;
  delete[] buffer;
}
```

and to send the checksum string, I modified the code as:

```
EVP_DigestFinal_ex(mdctx, md_value, &md_len);
EVP_MD_CTX_destroy(mdctx);
char str[128] = { 0 };
char *ptr = str;
std::string ret;
for(i = 0; i < md_len; i++)
 {
    //_snprintf(checksum_msg+cx,md_len-cx,"%02x",md_value[i]);
     sprintf(ptr,"%02x", md_value[i]);
     ptr += 2;
 }

ret = str;
/* Call this once before exit. */
EVP_cleanup();
return ret;
```

As for the wrong checksum earlier, the problem was associated in how windows keeps the line feed. As suggested by [Zangetsu](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1662069/zangetsu), Windows was making text file as `CRLF`, but linux and the site I mentioned earlier was using `LF`. Thus there was difference in the checksum value. For files other than text, eg `dll` the code now computes correct checksum as string

Answer (score 0):

MS-DOS used the CR-LF convention,So basically while saving the file in windows, `\r\n` comes in effect for carriage return and newline. And while testing on online (given by you),  only  `\n` character comes in effect. 
Thus either you have to check the checksum of `Test Message\r\nHello World\r\n` in string which is equivalent to creating and reading file in windows(as given above), which is the case here.

However, the checksum of files,wherever created, will be same.

Note: your code works fine :)